# Exclude multiple product ID's from wordpress coupon plugin with php

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

How do you get this code to call out multiple products instead of just 1 like it does now?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_coupon_is_valid_for_product', 'quadlayers_exclude_product_from_product_promotions', 9999, 4 );
function quadlayers_exclude_product_from_product_promotions( $valid, $product, $coupon, $values ) {
    // PRODUCT ID = 813869026091
    if ( 813869026091 == $product->get_id() ) {
        $valid = false;
    }
    
    return $valid;
}
```

I am trying to get this statement to say if the id is `005` OR `077` then exclude it from the coupon.  Right now I can only get 1 ID in the code (I don't know PHP very well).  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_coupon_is_valid_for_product', 'quadlayers_exclude_product_from_product_promotions', 9999, 4 );

function quadlayers_exclude_product_from_product_promotions( $valid, $product, $coupon, $values ) {

    if ( in_array($product->id, [1, 3, 5] ) {
        $valid = false;
    }

    return $valid;
}
```